# Application freezes if TCP port is not open on server when trying to connect

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, freeze, ports

I have a function that checks if a port is open on a certain IP. It does that by checking for a `SocketException`. My problem is that if the port is not open, it simply freezes. Here is my code:

```
Private Function IsPortOpen(ByVal Host As String, ByVal PortNumber As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Client As TcpClient = Nothing
    Try
        Client = New TcpClient(Host, PortNumber)
        Return True
    Catch ex As SocketException
        Return False
    Finally
        If Not Client Is Nothing Then
            Client.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

I have tried adding a timeout to the connection, trying to catch a basic `Exception`, and as an error. Still does the same thing. Returns true just fine if it is able to connect, but freezes if it is not. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling the parameterless constructor of TcpClient and then try to open it via `TcpClient.ConnectAsync` ? According to MSDN this does not block whereas `TcpClient(Host, PortNumber)` does block.

Comment: Like this?       `Private Function IsPortOpen(ByVal Host As String, ByVal PortNumber As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim Client As TcpClient = Nothing
        Try
            Client = New TcpClient
            Client.ConnectAsync(Host, PortNumber)
            Return True
        Catch ex As SocketException
            Return False
        Finally
            If Not Client Is Nothing Then
                Client.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Function`

Comment: Since ConnectAsync is an async method  you have to either create a Task/Thread to call it or make IsPortOpen `async` and `await` the ConnectAsync call.

Comment: Async sockets do not support timeouts. It's the easiest option to use sync sockets on a new task.

Comment: "*but freezes*" how long did you wait?